# Detecting particular text in image

Tags: javascript, html, opencv, web, ocr

Is there any html program using javascript,

1. To detect a particular text in given image
2. highlight it with rectangular box around it and
3. get the coordinates of corners of rectangle box?

Input Image: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3sy6.png

Let's say I want to search for "Computer":

Then Expected Output should be:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Hxt.png
with coordinates in console
.

Answer (score -1):

To do OCR (Optical Character Design) with JS, you can use [Tesseract.js](https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/)

Here is how it works ([from the repo](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs)):

```
import Tesseract from 'tesseract.js';

Tesseract.recognize(
  'https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/img/eng_bw.png',
  'eng',
  { logger: m => console.log(m) }
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  console.log(text);
})
```